# implicit declaration of function 'gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name' is invalid in C99

Tags: node.js, macos, mongodb

I'm trying to learn Node.js version 4.2.1 and when I tried to install mongoose onto the project, there was a warning message as below, however, [this](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/issues/194) on github does not provide solution on osx. `apt-get install libkrb5-dev` seems doesn't apply to osx environment. Btw I'm running os x El Capitan. How to solve this problem?

```
> kerberos@0.0.15 install /Users/caoyang/WebstormProjects/Nodejs/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
../lib/kerberosgss.c:509:13: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        maj_stat = gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name(&min_stat,
                   ^
1 warning generated.
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?